# how to skip the first line in CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I want to skip the Name,Path which is the first line when it generates the CSV file. I dont know how to do so and I have no idea how to do so .

here is my code:

```
function Get-Path{
    param($Object)

    $path = $object.Name
    $parent = Get-View $Object.ExtensionData.ResourcePool
    while($parent){
    $path = $parent.Name + "/" + $path

        if($parent.Parent){
            $parent = Get-View $parent.Parent
        }
        else{$parent = $null}
    }
    $path
}

Get-VM | Select Name,
@{N="Path";E={(Get-Path -Object $_) -replace "^.*?Resources"}} | Export-csv C:\izaz\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to export a CSV file with no header is to use ConvertTo-Csv and then use Select-Object to skip the first line:

```powershell
Get-VM `
| Select Name, @{N="Path";E={(Get-Path -Object $_) -replace "^.*?Resources"}} `
| ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation `
| Select-Object -Skip 1 `
| Set-Content -Path C:\izaz\test.csv
```

Comment: I came to post almost this exact solution.  Well done Bacon, this is the ideal answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Import-CSV -Header $StringWithAlternateHeader will set the header for the array you are importing the CSV into.  It does NOT REPLACE any existing header.  If you do not remove the old header from the CSV prior to import, then the old header will become a record in the array.

```
Example CSV:
Name,Age
Sally,15
Paul,14

$Array = Import-CSV .\example.csv
ARRAY[0] is Sally,15
ARRAY[1] is Paul,14

$Array = Import-CSV .\example.csv -Header @("Child","Age")
ARRAY[0] is Name,Age
ARRAY[1] is Sally,15
ARRAY[2] is Paul,14
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using the csv file with Import-csv, look at the -header parameter in the cmdlet documentation.  This parameter allows you to specify alternate column names instead of the ones stored in the csv file.

This is an alternative approach to the accepted answer.

Comment: Actually, this is the opposite of what the OP was asking (importing a CSV with no header instead of exporting a CSV with no header).

Comment: You are right, except that it also covers the case of exporting with one header and importing with a different header.  It's unclear from the OP whether the intent is to read the csv with ps or with some other app.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple IF statement to get rid of your header line.

```
$Array = Import-CSV .\example.csv -Header @("Child","Age")
if ($Array.Child -ne "Child)" {

ARRAY[1] is Sally,15
ARRAY[2] is Paul,14
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From PowerShell version 7.4, `ConvertTo-Csv` and `Export-Csv` will have a [`-NoHeader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.4) parameter:

```
Get-VM |
    Select Name, @{N="Path";E={(Get-Path -Object $_) -replace "^.*?Resources"}} |
    Export-Csv -NoHeader -NoTypeInformation
```

See also: [`#17527` Add `-NoHeader` switch to `Export-Csv` and `ConvertTo-Csv`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17527)